# Angular 6+ aside menu that changes main content

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm new to angular and I need to make an aside menu that will contain links, and these links will change the main content of the page (html layout and data from server) without refreshing the page. What is the best solution here? My only idea is to create one component with the aside menu and do something like this:

```
<aside>...</aside>
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="layout">
  <app-first-layout *ngSwitchCase="Layouts.First"></app-first-layout>
  <app-second-layout *ngSwitchCase="Layouts.Second"></app-second-layout>
  <app-third-layout *ngSwitchCase="Layouts.Third"></app-third-layout>
  ...
</ng-container>
```